# Having an object as a source of light, I.E. The Sun

Tags: graphics, directx

I'm working on a solar system model for class, I've had no real issues performing the different transforms on the objects + rotations.

But one requirement has me stumped, the Sun (located at 0,0,0) needs to be the source of light. I've gone ahead and created a point light at that location and configured it. The problem is that the sun isn't illuminated from the light, I'm guess because the light is coming from inside of it, so it's not reflecting off the outside to illuminate it, anyone have some tips on getting this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Light emitting objects are usually created by setting the "Emission" coefficient of the **material** to something other than black. with OpenGL this is done using `glMaterial()` and `GL_EMISSION`. With direct3d it looks like you'd want to change the `Emissive` parameter of `D3DMATERIAL9`

This coefficient allows you to create an object that appears to emit light and not just reflect it from other sources. Notice that this coefficient is a color, same as the diffuse and ambient coefficients so you can have a slightly yellow emission for a sun.

A sun generally also has a sort of "aura" around it. This cannot be simulated easily with the emission coefficient or other traditional lighting and shading mechanisms. You might want to try to fake it using a camera facing quad with an alpha blended texture.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the normals of the sun so that they face inwards (simply negate the x, y & z).  Now they will all point towards the point light.

TBH though its simpler to just render it as a special case and not light it.